# PHP Returning different JSON data for Android Dev

Tags: php, android, json

So I'm looking to return a JSON array containing specific data from a PHP page depending on what parameters/values I supply (the information will be used by an Android application). However I'm not convinced this is the best method to do this, for example I could use things like.

page.php?allcategories

page.php?specificcategory=12

page.php?specificpage=55

(I'd probably have about 7 different parameter types in total).

Obviously within the PHP script, I'd just have several conditional statements to test if these parameters exist.

Is there a more robust or simply 'better' method of doing what I'm trying to achieve? As this was my first idea.

Many thanks

Comment: If you're planning on returning your data as JSON, why not also have your page accept the request as an array of JSON params via POST, instead of having to concat a huge ugly URL full of GET params?

Comment: I'll only be using 1 parameter per query, as there isn't too much I need to filter. Passing a JSON seems like quite a good idea though, thanks.

Comment: Ah, in that case, keeping it simple like you've suggested should work fine. In order to avoid a long if/else chain though, I would consider having two params: type and id. For example: ?type=page&id=5 or ?type=cat&id=77 -- that way you can just have a switch statement on type, to determine how you grab your data.